# NullPointerException when Inserting Data using ManyToMany in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, many-to-many

I have tried all I could but I keep getting NullPointerException Error.

I have two Spring boot entities that have been mapped together using ManyToMany mapping. These Entities are fine as all the tables are created.

However, when I try to insert data, I get a NullPointerException.

Can someone please point me to what I am doing wrong?

Below is the code that I'm using to insert the data:

```
import com.ait.aiadmin.model.Cluster;
import com.ait.aiadmin.model.Subscriber;
import com.ait.aiadmin.repository.ClusterRepository;
import com.ait.aiadmin.repository.SubscriberRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AiAdminApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AiAdminApplication.class, args);
        /*ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AiAdminApplication.class, args);

        String [] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String name: beanNames){
            System.out.println(name);
        }*/
    }

    @Component
    public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {
        private final SubscriberRepository subscriberRepository;
        private final ClusterRepository clusterRepository;

        @Autowired
        public DatabaseLoader(SubscriberRepository subscriberRepository, ClusterRepository clusterRepository) {

            this.subscriberRepository = subscriberRepository;
            this.clusterRepository = clusterRepository;
        } 

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void run (String...strings) throws Exception {

            Subscriber subscriber1 = new Subscriber("Olalekan Samuel", "Ogunleye", "olalekan@gmail.com");
            Cluster cluster1 = new Cluster("Aws-eu-west-1", "Ireland", "123.98.45", "Olalekan Samuel");
            subscriber1.clusters.add(cluster1);
            this.subscriberRepository.save(subscriber1);
            this.clusterRepository.save(cluster1);
    }
}
```

And below is the error that I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   com.ait.aiadmin.AiAdminApplication.main(AiAdminApplication.java:19)
>   [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_152]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.ait.aiadmin.AiAdminApplication$DatabaseLoader.run(AiAdminApplication.java:73)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.ait.aiadmin.AiAdminApplication$DatabaseLoader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d20028d3.invoke()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   com.ait.aiadmin.AiAdminApplication$DatabaseLoader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e72d57b.run()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     ... 11 common frames
>   omitted

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code for the `Subscriber`, but I would guess the NPE occurs, because `subscriber1.clusters` is not initialized. Make sure that all Collections in your entities are created correctly.

In my applications I often use the getter for a collection to initialize it, if it does not exist, e.g.:

```
public List<Something> getSomethings() {
    if (somethings == null) {
        somethings = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return somethings;
}
```

Comment: Guessing is seldom a correct answer. Should have been a comment or a question for clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps me. It is now perfect.